# Getting Some Specific Types of Log

Tags: security, logging, windows-event-log

I'm want to get some logs from my server, but not general logs like `syslog` that gives me a lot of random logs. I want to know how I can get logs of things like logins(with time, IP and username), commands that the user ran, process running at the time and things like this.

Answer (score 1):

For logins: look at the `last` command.

For what commands they ran: look at the `lastcomm` command.  Additionally, any privileged command run with `sudo` will be in the system logs.

Comment: Is there any way to make a routine to log each command, even without using `sudo`?

Comment: as root, just run `lastcomm user`.  In RHEL and Fedora, `lastcomm` is part of the "psacct" package.  In Debian, it is part of the "acct" package.

Comment: I can use the `last` command like this: `nohup last &` so I can make a history file, or it has any restrictions?

Comment: This history is already logged.  `last` just reads /var/log/wtmp by default.  If you type `last -f /var/log/wtmp`, you should see the same output as if you type `last` w/ no args.  If you need to read a previous (rotated) `wtmp` file, just use that as an argument instead.  e.g., `last -f /var/log/wtmp-20110801`.  If you need to keep longer logs, just change your log rotation schedules.

Answer (score 1):

To log commands run by people, you need to enable Linux Process Accounting.  This should be in a package named `acct` (on Debian, probably something similar on redhat-based distributions), and comes in two pieces.  The first is `accton` which is a command run at boot that tells the kernel to log everything that runs (your package should set this up for you).  The other part is a collection of utilities that read the log file and print useful information from it.  On Debian this includes

- `dump-acct` which decodes the binary log file and dumps the data as text
- `sa` which does more-or-less the same but focuses on extracting programs run.
- `lastcomm` which dumps the log for a specific terminal, user, or command.

And a few others for figuring out how long people were connected.  You'll need to decide what exactly you want to get from the logs, since a lot of stuff is recorded, but [this site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html) has some examples of things you can do.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You might want to enable the BASH-history feature and enable timestamps there. But this will not give you the processes running at a certain time.